# Filter Channel Entries by status and "NOT" category

Tags: categories, status

Trying to run a channel entries loop where I filter on both status value and the fact that the category is NOT a specific category.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" status="open|Unavailable Online|Sold Out" category="not 8" sort="desc"}
```

Basically I want to get products in three different statuses and then ensure that I'm not showing products that are also in category 8.

The query works if I want to do category="8" but the **not** flag doesn't seem to do anything and it just ends up showing all products.

Does ExpressionEngine not allow this?

Comment: I could be wrong but I thought status' could only be one word and you have a space in there. So I'm curious if that's breaking your loop. That might not be the case but I would shy away from that personally!

Comment: Thanks but doesn't seem to make a difference, the official documentation gives two word status names as examples.

Comment: What ExpressionEngine version are you using?

Comment: Using version 2.7.3